# I set default JsonSerializer to Utf8Json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serialization, utf8json

Using c# 8 and .netcore 3.1.

I've read [HERE](https://michaelscodingspot.com/the-battle-of-c-to-json-serializers-in-net-core-3/) that **Utf8Json** library process json serialization and deserialization faster that **NewtonsoftJson**.

We've recently upgraded our servers code from **.netcore 2.2 to 3.1** mostly for performance improvements.
Thus, it is reasonable that we also use the best serialization library.

So my questions are:

1. In `Startup.cs` there is this

   ```
   services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
   {
       options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
   });
   ```

And I want it to use a different library, so I found out that I can use `.AddJsonOptions` but I cannot figure out how to set default serializer, even after using my google-fu skills.

2. Since I've been using `[JsonProperty("<name>")]` everywhere in my code in order to reduce json string size, do I need to format everything for the new serializer or is there a way to make him consider the property attribute ? (attribute is Newtonsoft)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Ori you can use Utf8json in net core 3.1 projects.

Use

`[DataMember(Name = "RoleType")]
public string Role_Type { get; set; }`

Instead of

`[JsonProperty("<name>")]`

To use Utf8json formatters in Asp.Net core you need add the formatters as mentioned below.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews()


    // Add Utf8Json formatters
    .AddMvcOptions(option =>
    {
        option.OutputFormatters.Clear();
        option.OutputFormatters.Add(new JsonOutputFormatter (StandardResolver.Default));
        option.InputFormatters.Clear();
        option.InputFormatters.Add(new JsonInputFormatter ());
    });
}
```

You can also refer below link for the formatters.
https://github.com/neuecc/Utf8Json/blob/master/src/Utf8Json.AspNetCoreMvcFormatter/Formatter.cs

I am using utf8json and its working great for us.

Comment: Thanks! will using DataMember also work if i still use Newtonsoft in other projects that still use .netcore 2.1?

Comment: They're documentatio has got to be the worst ever... not a single example!